# Zippy/EMACS G1W2-5760V3V Power supply manual or pinout information

Tags: power-supply-unit

I now have two different sizes of emac's power supplies and both have 2 extra pairs of wires, Red and black as well as yellow and black.  On the model above they both have 2pin push connectors with wings slimier to a 3 pin fan header on the other one on pair is like that while the other has a different kind of rounded connector.  I have never been able to find a manual to explain what they are.  the only thing I could think of was indicator lights for if a power supply went bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [G1W2-5760V3V Manual](https://b2b.rosch-computer.de/shop/file.php?aid=5667&sku=NT-G1W2-5760V3V&type=application%2Fpdf) on the last page it is documented:

> 11.0 Warning method
>         11.1 Audio alarm (buzzer sound, resetable)
>         11.2 Fault LED
>         11.3 Power defective signal delivery (TTL,Lowactive)

It seems these are:

> B1 2P TTL Signal BLACK RED
>   B4 2P BUZZER Reset BLACK YELLOW

The LED connector should be black/blue or red/black/green.

Please compare your connectors with the ones in
[HARNESS CONN_for INDEX_Ver 2_1030409.pdf](http://www.zippy.com/backend/DownLoad/DownLoad/Power/HARNESS%20WORKING%20SHEET/HARNESS%20CONN_for%20INDEX_Ver%202_1030409.pdf), page 5/7